# Does a woman who gives her eggs become yoledet

Tags: halacha, medicine, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, pregnancy-birth, yoreh-deah

In Leviticus  12:1-4 it states that a woman is impure for 7 days after birth, known as Yoledet. This is a status with similar rules to niddah. My question is, does this Halacha  apply to a woman who gives her  eggs, when her baby is  born?

Comment: These are such easy questions even my wagon driver can answer them.

Comment: Seems interesting enough to think about, and such questions can sometimes have surprising answers. It’s not like mi yodea has an over abundance of activity

Comment: @AviAvraham I think you missed the reference to a well known legend: https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/driver-switches-places/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is no vaginal delivery, there is no din of yoledes. In fact, Shulchan Aruch [YD 194:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.194.14?lang=bi) says that in the rare case of a caesarean birth that had zero vaginal discharge, there is no din of yoledes, niddah, or zivah:

> יוצא דופן אם לא יצא דם אלא דרך דופן אמו טהורה מלידה ומנדה ומזיבה:

> A Caesarean birth - if no blood emerges, even through her uterine wall, its mother is pure from birth-impurity and from menstruation-impurity and from blood flow-impurity.